# Base64.getDecoder().decode in C#

Tags: c#, base64, decode

I need a equivalent C# code for `Base64.getDecoder().decode` Java code. 
I have tried something like the following in C#

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(embedCode);
string decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decodedText);
```

But the string has some special characters like 0��\u0002B\0�*-\u0017���c\u001e�aֺ]���qr����`. How can I achieve this in C#

Comment: _"How can I achieve this in C#"_: is the source data actually a string in Java? You can't use _text encoding_ (e.g. UTF8) for arbitrary binary data. Moving on from that, is the string UTF8 encoded in Java?

Comment: Your code is correct for Base64 encoded UTF8 bytes. So your assumptions about the input data are wrong.

Comment: Encoding UTF8 in Base64 is not very common or sensible, it would only be needed for a 7-bit data channel.

Comment: @John, Base64.getDecoder().decode will give byte array, I need an equivalent C# code.

Comment: @Golda - look again at line 1 of your code. How would you describe `decodedBytes` and how does that differ from this "byte array" that you're looking for?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, It gives different results in Java and C#

Comment: Then the Java code is doing more than *just* calling `Base64.getDecoder().decode` because line 1 of the C# code is precisely going to do that action.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, the byte result is differ from JAVA to C#

Comment: Well, verify all steps. Start by checking the base64 input (length, first and last chars). They should be the same n Java and C#.  Then compare the length of the `byte[]` and so on.

Comment: The Java decode method doesn't convert the resultant byte array to a string, and you haven't shown your equivalent Java code for that. On that basis, my comment is still valid. On the basis of your question, your byte data either isn't encoded with UTF8, or UTF8 text encoding has been mistakenly used for non-textual data.

Comment: If you just need the equivalent code, as you state, then remove the last 2 lines of the code from your question and use the byte array that was returned.

Comment: @John has the answer. Golda, is there some reason you have the additional code? Please [edit] to explain.

Answer (score 0):

'\u0002' is the 'start of text' character for unicode encoding.

So use

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(embedCode);
string decodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decodedBytes);
```

And please don't try to encode Unicode text as ASCII, Unicode has a wider character range, which ASCII will not be able to recognize. So use unicode encoding again to write to bytes.